# Variable inside geolocation string sql

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I'm trying to make some geolocations in mysql database. I've got it working with a simple insert statement, the one below.

```
INSERT INTO location 
VALUES ("London", ST_GeometryFromText('Point(10.0000 10.0000)'));
```

My problem is when i want to insert all my cities. I'm inserting from a tsv file having 100.000+ cities. But when i wan't to create the geo point and can't insert the values because 'point()' required to have quotes around it and it's seen as a string. @col5 and 6 have the lat and lng, i've testet that. How can i insert the values from @col5 @col6 in the point object / ('string')

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'cities.txt'
INTO TABLE location
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@col1, @col2, @col3, @col4, @col5, @col6) 
SET city_name=@col2, geom=ST_GeometryFromText('point(@col5 @col6)');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use concat as in:

```
SET city_name=@col2, geom=ST_GeometryFromText(CONCAT('point(', @col5,  @col6, ')'));
```

Comment: Great it worked! In your answer your just missing the space between the two. geom=ST_GeometryFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', (at)col5, ' ', (at)col6, ')')) But thanks a lot!